# How to split a string by a specific character?

Tags: c#, asp.net, string

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do i split a String into multiple values?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/242718/how-do-i-split-a-string-into-multiple-values)

I have a string 0001-102525 . I want to split it into 0001 and 102525.How can i do it?
Regards,

Comment: Did you actually google this? http://www.google.se/search?gcx=w&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=split+string+c%23

Comment: How about using the Search before asking a question? Or Google? Really...

Comment: Maybe he does not have an idea doing this..

Comment: first oyu have to search ......

Comment: I think answers on SO come up faster than google search :)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

```
var myString = "0001-102525";
var splitString = myString.Split("-");
```

Then access either like so:

`splitString[0]` and `splitString[1]`

Don't forget to check the count/length if you are splitting user inputted strings as they may not have entered the '-' which would cause an `OutOfRangeException`.

Answer (score 9):

How about:

```
string[] bits = text.Split('-');
// TODO: Validate that there are exactly two parts
string first = bits[0];
string second = bits[1];
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use C# split method - [MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.split)

Answer (score 0):

```
string strData = "0001-102525";
//Using List
List<string> strList = strData.Split('-').ToList();
string first = strList.First();
string last = strList.Last();

//Using Array
string[] strArray = strData.Split('-');
string firstItem = strArray[0];
string lastItem = strArray[1];
```

Answer (score 0):

```
string strToSplit = "0001-102525"; //Can be of any length and with many '-'s
string[] arrStr = strToSplit.Split('-');
foreach (string s in arrStr) //strToSplit can be with many '-'s.  This foreach loop to go thru entire arrStr string array
{
    MessageBox.Show(s);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
string myString = "0001-102525";

//to split the string

string [] split = myString.Split("-");

//to display the new strings obtained to console

foreach(string s in split)
{
  if(s.Trim() !="")
    Console.WriteLine(s);
}
```