# How to split a string array using char as delimiter

Tags: c#

I want to add `'` char as delimiter to my string array but I have error telling conversion string to char impossible.

I see this [How to split a string by a specific character?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8338747/how-to-split-a-string-by-a-specific-character)

```
string ineedtosplitthis = "i want 'to' split this";
string[] splitTest = ineedtosplitthis.Split("'").ToString();
```

Comment: Remove the `.ToString()` part.

Comment: This seems oddly similar to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72133899/how-to-split-a-string-with-a-char-character

Comment: @gunr2171 Yep, I noticed that too. I even thought it was a repost by the same u̵s̵e̵r̵ account.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issues is that you have the `.ToString()` after your statement.
Change it to this:

```
string ineedtosplitthis = "i want 'to' split this";
string[] splitTest = ineedtosplitthis.Split('\'');
```

The reason why this code doesn't work: 
`string[] splitTest = ineedtosplitthis.Split("'").ToString();`
Is because you are converting it to a `string` via `ToString();`, while assigning it to a `string[]`.

`Split();` already returns a `string[]`, so there is no need to convert it.
Hope this explanation helped :)

Comment: Although you are correct @xyve, explain why (and in detail) since that will help the SO community

Comment: I still have impossible conversion string to char (i use .net 4.7)

Comment: Try changing the line of code from `string[] splitTest = ineedtosplitthis.Split("'");` to `string[] splitTest = ineedtosplitthis.Split('\'');`

Comment: @xyve yes, that's correct. 4.7 doesn't have an overload that accepts a string (or string[] param).

Comment: @gunr2171 Yeah, I totally forgot about that, I should've read more carefully at his error.